# Usings multiple conditions in select (dplyr)

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I want to choose certain columns of a dataframe with `dplyr::select()` using `contains()` more than ones. **I know there are other ways to solve it, but I wonder whether this is possible inside `select()`.** An example:

```
df <- data.frame(column1= 1:10, col2= 1:10, c3= 1:10)
library(dplyr)
names(select(df, contains("col") & contains("1")))
```

This gives an error but I would like the function to give `"column1"`.

I expected that `select()` would allow a similiar appraoch as `filter()` where we can set multiple conditions with operators, i.e. something like `filter(df, column1 %in% 1:5 & col2 != 2)`.

EDIT

I notice that my question is more general and I wonder whether it is possible to pass any combinations in `select()`, like `select(df, contains("1") | !starts_with("c"))`, and so on. But can't figure out how to make such a function.

Comment: Can you nest select statements? `names(select(select(df, contains("col")), contains("1")))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `select_if` and `grepl`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
select_if(grepl("col", names(.)) & grepl(1, names(.)))


#   column1
#1        1
#2        2
#3        3
#4        4
#5        5
#6        6
#7        7
#8        8
#9        9
#10      10
```

If you want to use `select` with `contains` you could do something like this:

```
df %>% 
select(intersect(contains("col"), contains("1")))
```

This can be combined in other ways, as mentioned in the comments:

```
df %>% 
select(intersect(contains("1"), starts_with("c")))
```

Comment: @machine, I've edited my answer to include a `select` option using `contains`

Comment: Thanks, +1. In fact I notice that my question is more general and I wonder whether it is possible to pass any combinations in select, like `select(df, contains("1") & starts_with("c"))`, and so on.. But can't figure out how to make such a function.

Comment: This seems to work for me using `intersect` in the same way as my answer: `df %>% select(intersect(contains("1"), starts_with("c")))`. Using `&` won't work, we use `intersect` to act as the `and`, as without it would be sort of an `or` statement

Comment: Interesting, but I can't go on yet. How is it about situations like `select(df, contains("1"), -starts_with("c"))` or `select(df, contains("1") | -starts_with("c"))` and so on. I am stuck here and I think this is because I missunderstand the function itself.

Comment: `intersect` for AND, `union` for OR, `setdiff` for AND NOT, e.g., `select(df, setdiff(contains("1"), starts_with("c")))` is contains 1 and doesn't start with c. `select(df, union(contains("1"), starts_with("c")))` for contains 1 OR starts with c.

Comment: It won't work for OR, but the more ANDs you have the more I prefer the solution chaining multiple select calls. `df %>% select(contains("1")) %>% select(-starts_with("c"))` seems clearer than `setdiff`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also chain two `select` calls:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(column1 = 1:10, col2 = 1:10, c3 = 1:10)

df %>% 
  select(contains("col")) %>% 
  select(contains("1"))
```

Not too elegant for one-line lovers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `dplyr::intersect` function

`select(df, intersect(contains("col"), contains("1")))`